# Maven multimodule mojo not executing

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to install a custom plugin (mojo) first and then execute the goal. I would want this to happen in one go but as of now using below code i am getting build errors. Not sure if i'm going right in below code so that i can install plugin first and then code inside mojo would get executed.

ParentProject:

```
  <groupId>com.io</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Parent</name>
  <description>ThisisParent</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>Child1Plugin</module>
    <module>ChildFramework</module>
  </modules>
```

Child1Plugin-pom.xml

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.io</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Child1Plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<name>Child</name>
<description>ThisisChild</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.parent.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>ChildFramework</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>mydata</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

ChildFramework-pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ChildFramework</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <name>Childtwo</name>
    <description>Thisischildtwo</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.io</groupId>
                <artifactId>ChildFramework</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>mydata</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The below mojo is inside src/main/java folder of ChildFramework module.

```
@Mojo(name = "mydata", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class Feat extends AbstractMojo {    
    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MyMOJO");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

ChildFramework can't use itself as a plugin (because that's a circular dependency). I think the changes you need are these:

- Child1Plugin: remove the ChildFramework plugin element
- ChildFramework: change `<packaging>` to `jar` and change the `<artifactId>` of the plugin to `Child1Plugin`
- move the mojo code from the ChildFramework module to the Child1Plugin module

Comment: For thr 3rd change I can move the mojo code but all my framework classes reside in the ChildFramework thats why I m using mojo in ChildFramework so that I can make use of all those classes.Is there a way I can install my plugin first and then execute mojo from ChildFramework module?

Comment: No, you cannot add a plugin to itself. You need to restructure your project. Put common code in some `common` module and use it as dependency somewhere else.

Comment: is it possible to install the plugin and run mojo at the same time ?

Comment: You can build a plugin and run it from some other module. You cannot run it from the plugin module itself.